# Conditionally change a field to null or not null

Tags: sql-server, null, conditional-statements

I'm new to StackOverflow and this is my first question on the forum..

I am trying to create a table in MS SQL Server 2008 with a constraint that makes a field optional or required based on the contents of another field in the same table.

Here is the code I have so far...

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE (
C# INT,
NAME VARCHAR(20) ,
CREDIT TINYINT,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PREREQUISITE VARCHAR(60),
CONSTRAINT PK_COURSE PRIMARY KEY (C#)
CONSTRAINT CK_CREDIT CHECK (CREDIT IN (1,2,3,4,5)),
CONSTRAINT UC_NAME UNIQUE(NAME),  ...
```

Here is the condition: PREREQUISITE can be null unless C# > 3000 then PREREQUISITE cannot be null. I have been pulling my hair out trying to make that work.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You should include an explicit question, ending in a `?`. That way we can  understand your problem better.

Answer (score 2):

```
,
CONSTRAINT CK_CN_PREREQ
  CHECK (([C#] > 3000 AND PREREQUISITE IS NOT NULL) OR ([C#] <= 3000))
```

`C#` is a terrible column name, by the way.